# How to optimize spark to write data to s3 by joining 2 tables of 20TB each

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, optimization, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We are joining 2 tables, each 20TB in a spark job.
Running it on r5.4x large EMR cluster.

How can we optimize it, can anyone share few parameters to finetune the job and help it run quicker.

**More Details :**
Both input tables are timestamp partitioned.
Size of files in each partition is around 128MB each.
Input and output file format is parquet.
Output is written to an external glue table and stored on s3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One of the major practices is to write out to local HDFS and distcp to S3. At least tat is what AWS told me on my last AWS project.

Comment: Can you show the code that you are running? Also, where are the tables located i.e. are they hive tables, delta tables, glue tables or something else? What are the current optimisations that you have tried?

Comment: Very broad question imho.

Comment: @VikasSaxena - The source tables are hive external tables stored on s3 in parquet format.   Both the tables are huge, hence broadcast isn't possible. The time taken to test parameters is very huge and we last terminated while the job was in progress for more than 4 hours. The requirement is to get it to less than 2 hours.

Comment: @thebluephantom - yes I understand, too broad. Want to get a few inputs, not looking for a perfect answer for now. By writing out to local HDFS, would you suggest writing the output to HDFS and then distcp to S3? Asking on the premise that the left outer join results in multiple matches with the second table and that the output would be around the same size.

Comment: Thats one of the guidelines when i architect for aws. Aws tell u that as well.

Comment: @GangadharDalli, you may want to include more details in the question such as sizes of both tables, your join query, structure and some sample data specially about partitions columns so that someone can help you out, there is no general rule of thumb as thebluephantom suggested, but if you are using spark, in general with spark, you may be able to skip/filter a lot of data before the actual join making it easier to do it. post the code any I am sure experts here may help you to optimise it.

Comment: in past, i have done joins with more than billion records in one partition against another table with  10 million records in one partition which use to take around 17-20 mins (due to cluster load as multiple jobs were competing for resources so I am sure you have either got incorrectly partitions tables or a bad code. High chances that your job performance may improve by revisiting partitioning strategy.